# Read username and password from a file

Tags: python

How can i read text, e.g., username and password from a file line-by-line in Python? For example, i can achieve this in shell/bash:

```
#!/bin/bash

AUTH='/authentication/account.txt'
U=$(sed -n 1p ${AUTH})
P=$(sed -n 2p ${AUTH})
```

and inside the file /authentication/account.txt are my username and password line-by-line like this:

```
username
userpass
```

Comment: Have you _tried_ to research this? There are a million and one sources + questions on how to do this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should not be storing unencrypted login details in text files.

However, here is a very simple solution anyway:

```
f=open("/authentication/account.txt","r")
lines=f.readlines()
username=lines[0]
password=lines[1]
f.close()
```